# Linux USB debug connection to LuminaryMicro evaluation board

Tags: linux, embedded, usb, codesourcery

I am trying to connect a Stellaris LM3S8962 evaluation kit to a linux host machine.  I am using the CodeSourcery G++ for the development toolchain.  When I try to run a helloworld example the connection fails with this message:

> arm-stellaris-eabi-sprite: error:
>   E104. I/O Error communicating with USB
>   Device. arm-stellaris-eabi-sprite:
>   waiting for GDB connection, to pass
>   error along warning: Remote failure
>   reply: E.fatal.E104. I/O Error
>   communicating with USB Device.
>   arm-stellaris-eabi-sprite: error:
>   E002. Not initialized

When I connect the evaluation board with the USB cable it seems the device is made available to the system:

> Mar 24 14:37:16 n6-ws2 kernel: usb
>   5-2: USB disconnect, address 5 Mar 24
>   14:37:18 n6-ws2 kernel: usb 5-2: new
>   full speed USB device using uhci_hcd
>   and address 6 Mar 24 14:37:19 n6-ws2
>   kernel: usb 5-2: configuration #1
>   chosen from 1 choice

Also, it seems that I can connect in some way via the command line tool (but I do get some strange characters):

> [mlong@n6-ws2 bin]$
>   ./arm-stellaris-eabi-sprite -i
>   CodeSourcery ARM Debug Sprite
>   (Sourcery G++ 4.4-104) armusb:
>   [speed=] ARMUSB device
>   armusb:///�̙ - ؎� (�̙)

Does anyone have any suggestions I could try?

Thanks a lot,

Mike

Comment: Could you clarify a little more.  Do you mean you're trying to connect a USB debugger to the host machine?

Comment: Yes, I`m trying to connect the USB debugger from the linux host to the target evaluation board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the bump, but this is one of the few pages around that deals with this error and a bunch of those are just redirects to this page :P

Anyway, it turns out that in my case this was a permissions issue. If you execute:

```
sudo ./arm-stellaris-eabi-sprite -i
```

then you will get an uncorrupt name for the device. Then it becomes an issue of giving the user the required permissions for the USB device. To do this you need to alter the file at:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
```

find the libusb device nodes line and change the mode to 0666. Do a reboot and things will be sweet.

If anyone has a better solution let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out soon after I posted the question but it totally slipped my memory to update with an answer.  Good work on making the world a little better!